# No compile time TypeScript errors for enums

Tags: enums, compiler-errors, typescript

This looks strange for me but TypeScript 0.9.5 compiler does not generate any compile time errors when I write something like:

```
enum A {
    a,
    b,
    c,
}

var x : A = 20;
```

To compare C# compiler will raise the following error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

As for me it would be better to specify such cast explicitly:

```
var x : A = <A>20;
```

Is it an intentional design and is required in some use case or this was jut missed?

Answer (score 2):

It's intentional. The fact that the C# compiler knows what you meant (*"are you missing a cast?"*) is instructive -- in general, TypeScript errs on the side of flexibility over strictness. Some people want a cast to be required here "to show that you thought about it"; the assumption in this case is that you are always thinking while programming and should not be bothered unless something is more obviously wrong.

Comment: It seems it can be useful to add some kind of TypeScript warning for this (that can be later treated as error if you want)

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Numbers can be assigned to enums without a cast and vice versa.